# SQL, piece of data knows what table it comes from

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have 4 tables containing data of different categories:

```
Audiobooks
Music
Text 
Films
```

Each table contains relevant to the category data, i.e.

`Films` would contain .mp4 files and `Music` will contain .mp3 and so on.

An extra table exists called `Content`, which has all the data from all other 4 tables and contains columns with extra information about the files.

If I extract a row from the Content's table, I want to know where that file originated from (what table it comes from), WITHOUT having to search through ALL the tables and see which one contains that filename or UUID (coz filenames may clash), and without having to put an extra column in the Contents table saying the tablename of that file.

I searched Google and StackOverflow for similar qns but none gave a desired answer yet. Maybe I'm asking for too much.

Comment: Probably you dont need to do this.You want some sort of "watermark" on your sql data?

Comment: The way you describe it? I think that's impossible. If you want to accomplish that you absolutely must have an extra field to specify it.

Comment: If I understand correctly (not sure I do): you have duplicate data in your DB which you've copied manually. You want to find out what table you copied it from, without reading the source tables. That's physically impossible: bytes stored in a computer disk do not have "memory". All this feels like you are using a relational database engine trying to emulate a file system. It was your choice not to take benefit of DB features; you'll have to live with that, or change your mind.

Comment: You should create an extra column in Contents, or maybe organize the id's of each table like: 1xxx - Films, 2xxx - Music, etc. But is sure that what you want requires a specific design to be possible, if not you can't do it.

Comment: Currently I have a column 'Category' in the Contents table which fills the tablename for each row of data. I wasn't sure if that was the best way to do it but if that's the only reasonable/efficient way, then I can tell my manager to stop pestering me about it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes Val37, having a category column is much better then duplicating all data in different category tables. When you have that you can still make views of the Content table which emulate current behaviour, although I don't think that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without changing your database design:**

You could change the strategy you store your UUID's, so the every text will begin with "TXT" and "Film with "MP4", etc. That way, some simple logic on your database access object wrapper like

```
If (UUID.substring(0,3) = "MP4") sqlQuery = SELECT * FROM Films WHERE UUID = SqlUUID
If (UUID.substring(0,3) = "TXT") sqlQuery = SELECT * FROM Text WHERE UUID = SqlUUID
```

etc.

If you're not using a DAO wrapper then you'll have to write the string on SQL...and that is very messy. On the other hand, if you have something on the `Contents` table that distinguishes between the different files, for example a `file extension` column, you could just make 2 queries, the first one to find out which table you should be querying.

**Overall though, Pieter is right; you should change your database design.**

I don't see why you couldn't have merged the `Content` table with the other tables. If the length of output is a problem, just select the relevant columns instead of everything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like your Database design. This could be solved with a better design without duplicate information in different places.

Having said that: you could make an extra table with all the ids from your Content table and a reference to what table: Audiobooks, Music, Text or Films and what id in that table the record refers to.

Why do you need the information in all those tables, why isn't the Content Table enough?

Comment: Let's put it like this: Contents has things which are common to all categories, such as a filename, thumbnail, description and a few others, whereas all the other tables contain things which are specific for each category, e.g. text has number of pages, which film and music wouldn't have. Contents table is connected to all other tables through appropriate foreign keys on the UUID. I have avoided duplication to the maximum.

Comment: You didn't put it like that, you put it like this: "An extra table exists called Content, which has all the data from all other 4 tables". ALL data from ALL other 4 tables.